# Index was outside the bounds of the array; Exception is thrown when run outside of Visual Studio

Tags: c#

Index was outside the bounds of the array is thrown when importing a CSV file outside of Visual Studio.

When this is run in Visual Studio it runs perfectly fine.

```
   private void uiImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            List<string[]> data = parseCSV(@openFileDialog1.FileName);
            foreach (string[] column in data)
            {
                if (counter == 0) { counter++; continue; }; // Skip the first row
                if (checkAccount(column[1]))
                {
                    createAccount(column[0].Trim(), column[1].Trim(), column[2].Trim(), @column[3].Trim(), column[4].Trim(), column[5].Trim(), column[6].Trim(), column[7].Trim(), column[8].Trim(), column[9].Trim(), column[10].Trim(), column[11].Trim());
                }

            }
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Clearly some `column` doesn't have 12 elements.

Comment: The way you are trimming those colomns is really dangerous and is probably what is going wrong. You might want to itterate through the columns with a for loop

Comment: Without concentrating on the code itself, how is the CSV read in parseCSV? If you have different results outside Visual Studio, changes are it's a culture difference. (assuming you are sure the files themselves are identical). Of course as mentioned, it's also safer to write the code in such a matter that you can handle missing columns and such.

Comment: I think the best option would be to use a CSV parser like NewtonSoft, and create a DTO.